# Calling a webservice from a custom sharepoint webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, sharepoint

I have added a custom webservice to a sharepoint 2013 webapplication. This webservice has to call an other webservice ouside sharepoint. When i create a new instance of the webservice client i get the following error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'WebService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I use this code to create the client:

```
using (WebServiceClient serviceClient = new WebServiceClient())
{
}
```

There is an endpoint added in the web.config and when i create a webservice client in a Usercontrol it is working fine. Why is it not working when i create the webservice client in my cusstom webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the webservice was not working because the webservice is placed in a virtual directory with its own web.config. This web.config does not contain the endpoint configuration which is added by the Webconfigmodification. I solved this by adding the endpoint programmatically:

```
using (WebServiceClient serviceClient = new WebServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), 
        new EndpointAddress("endpointAddress")))
{
}
```